# How do I add a clear options icon on selecting an option in MaterialUI select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a clear options icon when any option is selected from the list of the options.

```
<Select
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position='end'>
        <ClearIcon />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
  //MenuProps={{ disableScrollLock: true }}
  //defaultValue={customer.swStatus}
  value={hwStatus}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setHwStatus(e.target.value);
    filterTable('SEARCH_BY_HW_STATUS', e.target.value);
  }}
  displayEmpty
  inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
  sx={{ fontSize: '15px', height: '40px' }}>
  <MenuItem value='Pending'>Pending</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value='Complete'>Completed</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just pass onClear event and update state to blank string.

Try like this, it might works!

Import this two icons:

```
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
```

Your **handleClearClick** event:

```
handleClearClick = () => {
 setHwStatus('');
}

<Select
  endAdornment={<IconButton sx={{visibility: score? "visible": "hidden"}} onClick={handleClearClick}><ClearIcon/></IconButton>}
    >
//MenuProps={{ disableScrollLock: true }}
//defaultValue={customer.swStatus}
value={hwStatus}
onChange={(e) => {
 setHwStatus(e.target.value);
 filterTable('SEARCH_BY_HW_STATUS', e.target.value);
}}
displayEmpty
inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
sx={{ fontSize: '15px', height: '40px' }}>
<MenuItem value='Pending'>Pending</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='Complete'>Completed</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the `handleClear` method to reset the state.

```js
const handleClear = () => {
  setHwStatus("");
  filterTable("SEARCH_BY_HW_STATUS", "");
};
```

In the `InputProps` you can add a `IconButton` with the `onClick`

```js
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";

...

InputProps={{
  startAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position="end">
      <IconButton onClick={handleClear}>
        <ClearIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </InputAdornment>
  ),
}}
```